# Git cloning in current directory

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to clone the HTML 5 Boiler Plate from GitHub, but it's creating a folder in my directory called html5bp. What I am trying to do is clone the contents directly into the directory without creating a sub directory. Here is what I'm using:

```
git clone http://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate.git
```

I know it's possible, but I'm new to using git so don't know the ins and outs of it just yet.

Comment: `cd ../` and try again.

Comment: `git clone someurl.git .`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the directory (which has to be empty):

```
git clone http://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate.git mydirectory
```

For more help on git commands, try `git help <command>`, e.g., `git help clone`.

Comment: This works perfectly. I was previously having to use the mv command and rm command to move and remove. This is much better! Thank you.

Comment: Going to comment since this answer covers most of it.  It's worth noting to answer the question that was asked and clone into the current directory is to `git clone http://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate.git ./`